# Styling select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot find any way to change the font styling in a Rails select_tag list

If I try this:

```
<%= select_tag :weight_lbs, options_for_select([['0', 0],['1', 1],['2', 2],['3', 3],['4', 4],['5', 5],['6', 6],['7', 7],['8', 8],['9', 9],['10', 10],['11', 11],['12', 12],['13', 13]]), :class => 'formfield'%>
```

then I can change the width of the select box in my CSS class but I cannot change anything else - height, font-size and color, eg, all have no affect

Similarly, if I try and change style at element level, and even using an example from Rails documentation

```
<%= select_tag 'testname', options_for_select(options_for_select([ "Denmark", ["USA", {:class => 'select'}], "Sweden" ]))%>
```

the class attribute has no affect on output (Chrome & Safari on a Mac, Rails 3.1)

So, how can I change the height & text styles within a select_tag in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Reddit. posted by [u/GroceryBagHead](https://www.reddit.com/user/GroceryBagHead/)

> You cannot style select options. Those are dependent and rendered by your OS/browser. It's possible to replace this control with html elements though.

He posted a link that's now dead for something called [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select). A google search should help you find more resources

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is old, but sure you can:

```
<%= select_tag :blah, options_for_select(@some_options), {:multiple => true, :style => "min-width: 200px"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check the page source generated by Rails. It will make easier to understand the HTML structure in order to select the elements in your CSS file.
Having the HTML code generated by Rails, your question became related to CSS.

You can include your select inside a div, for example:

```
<div class="myclass">
  <%= select_tag :weight_lbs, options_for_select([['0', 0],['1', 1],['2', 2],['3', 3],['4', 4],['5', 5],['6', 6],['7', 7],['8', 8],['9', 9],['10', 10],['11', 11],['12', 12],['13', 13]])%>
</div>
```

So your CSS:

```
.myclass select {
    font: # whatever you want
    ...
}

.myclass select option {
    # in case you want to style the options of a select
}
```

ETC...

Comment: In my first code snippet above, where I have :class => 'formfield', this now works but ONLY if there is a border or background element in the CSS, in which case all the other CSS elements work. If no border or background, then only the width element works. Don't know why that should be. Your suggestion of .myclass select option doesn't work at all, even with a border element in the CSS. I think it should, though. Seems very odd!

Answer (score 0):

A work around I used was installing a gem called [select2](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails)

```
gem 'select2-rails'
```

If you follow setup process in the docs, you can edit the dropdown list properties pretty easily in CSS. After some messing around in Chrome inspector, I found the relative tags.

```
/* The dropdown background */
.select2-dropdown{
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Individual styling of list items that are selected (previously chosen) */
.select2-results__option--selected {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #505050 !important;
}

 /* Individual styling of list items that are highlighted (mouse hover) */
.select2-results__option--highlighted {
  background-color: #e66d2d !important;
}
```

If you want to look into Chrome Inspector yourself, click on the "Select" form field and open the dropdown list. This creates a span element as a child of the body tag shown in the [screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj6a8.png).